# How do you hide a ModalPopupExtender embedded in an ASCX user control with no postback (through javascript )?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, modalpopupextender, ascx

I have an Asp.net application.
 Within that application I have a ModalPopupExtender embedded within an ASCX user control.
 I would like to be able to wire up a cancel button so I can hide the popup when user presses cancel
 without doing a post back.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<cc1:ModalPopupExtender ID="PopupExtender1" runat="server" PopupControlID="pnlPopup" BehaviorID="mdlPopupForm"
TargetControlID="btnHiddenSubmit" OkControlID="btnOkay" CancelControlID="btnCancel" 
Drag="true" PopupDragHandleControlID="PopupHeader" EnableViewState="true" 
BackgroundCssClass="modalBackground" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Here is the HTML for btnCancel

```
<input type="button" id="btnCancel" onclick="cancelPopupPanelClick()" value="Cancel" />
```

Here is the javascript:

```
   function cancelPopupPanelClick() {

    alert('CancelEventFired');
    var modalPopup = $find('PopupExtender1');
    if (modalPopup != null) {
        modalPopup.hide();
    }
}
```

The event fires fine. The issue I'm having is that I can't "Find" the modalPopup in order to hide it.
 Is this complicated by the fact that I have the ModalPopupExtender embedded in an ASCX control?

I have verified that the "AjaxControlToolkit.ToolkitScriptManager" is loaded in the containing ASPX page.

Can someone get me pointed in the right direction?

Thanks,
 JohnB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using invalid selector, try this:

```
var modalPopup = $('#PopupExtender1');
```

Comment: No, unfortunately that does not work. It returns []. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with being embedded in a user control (ASCX) or not.

Comment: Fixed this. I set the BehaviorID on my user control (ASCX) to be the same as that of my popup. I was able to call $find(behaviourID).hide().